# Permutations in which $d$ appears before $b$.

Tags: permutations

Consider all possible permutations of eight distinct elements $a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h$. In how many of them, will $d$ appear before $b$? Note that $d$ and $b$ may not necessarily be consecutive.

Comment: Choose two positions. There are only one way to place d and b in those two positions so that d appears before b.

Comment: Would there be a reason for $b$ to appear before $d$ more often than the other way around? Why (not)?

Comment: a personnal effort may be nice from ur end

Comment: Taking any permutation and putting d where b has been and b where d has been is a bijection with no fix-points that maps the subset "b before d" to "b after d". So the number of elements in those sets are equal and half the number of all permutations.

Comment: I did try have a solution I mean something that I think may be a solution.

Comment: So what is that thing that you "think may be a solution"?

Answer (score 2):

From these 8 elements we can create 8! permutations.

There is a one to one correspondence between the permutations where  $d$ appears after $b$ and the permutations where $d$ appears before $b$. This is a simple switching of the elements  $d$ and $b$.

Hence half of the 8! permutations will be so that  $d$ appears before $b$.
This equals 20160.

Comment: those kinds of shortcuts always miss their road to my intuition, nice trick !

Comment: I'm baffled. Can you assist pls? 1. How do you know anything about the "correspondence between the permutations where d appears after b and the permutations where d appears before b"? How do you know this is "one to one"? 
2. Then how do you deduce "half of the 8! permutations"?

Comment: Please edit your answer, rather than reply in comments that can get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

- By inventing a function f(n) where n is the range of b

$f(n)=(n-1)!*\binom{8-2}{8-n}(8-n)!$ the possible permutations where b is at the $n$th rank.

This gives outcome to f(2)+f(3)+..f(8) all valid permutations .